# Altcoins with plaintext transaction messaging

Tags: altcoin, transaction-messaging

I'm looking to compile a list of altcoins with plaintext transaction messaging embedded into the blockchain. If anyone knows of a coin that fits the bill then please share.

Comment: I have found OpenSourceCoin and Florincoin, we want to use TX messaging in our own private coin but neither of these coins have a proper commit history. Anyone know a TX messaging coin with decent source code history?

Answer (score 0):

check out: https://nxtwiki.org/wiki/Arbitrary_Messages

> The NXT Messaging system allows you to send and receive data on the
>   NXT Blockchain, thus allowing any Nxt account holder to communicate
>   directly with all other account holders.
>
> Messages can be attached to any Nxt transaction, making bookkeeping
>   easy, as you can tag all your transactions with a description. Project
>   developers can use the Messaging system to embed machine-readable data
>   within an Nxt transaction. This allows automated functions by reading
>   the data sent to you on the blockchain.
>
> Messaging is securely encrypted by default, but text or data can also
>   be sent unencrypted.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Ethereum](http://ethereum.org/) does not have a messaging system by default but, because it is programmable and you can store arbitrary data in the blockchain (more exactly, in a Merkle tree whose root is in the blockchain), you can develop it fairly easily.

It is actually a very common "my first Ethereum program", just after "hello, world" : http://jonathanpatrick.me/blog/ethereum-smtp https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1205/how-can-ethereum-be-used-to-send-messages-between-connected-machines https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Whisper and many many others